# How to loadAgent using VirtualMachine?

Tags: java-8, virtual-machine, aspectj, javaagents

I am trying to load "-javaagent:aspectjweaver1.9.1.jar" using VirualMachine. Below is the code

```
static {
    String nameOfRunningVM = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    int p = nameOfRunningVM.indexOf('@');
    String pid = nameOfRunningVM.substring(0, p);

    try {
        VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
vm.loadAgent("C:\\Users\\mehaboobkhan.p\\Desktop\\Project\\trunk\\Batches\\LookAhead\\lib\\aspectjweaver-1.9.1.jar");
        vm.detach();
        List<String> arguments = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am checking the if the agent is being loaded using getInputArguments and it has not. There is not error. I am using Java8.

I checked many similar question but unable to solve it. There ever possible paths of jar (relative and absolute).

Comment: Why do you assume that loading an agent at runtime changes the input arguments given at JVM startup?

Comment: @Holger Because if I provide javaagent in vm arguments in eclipse I can find it input arguments. I want it to work in similar way. I have written Aspect oriented programming and the jar has to be submitted to spark worker for execution.

Comment: Of course, when you provide something in vm arguments in eclipse, you will find it later-on in the list of vm input arguments. My question was, why do you expect to find something in the input arguments when you *don’t* specify it in the input arguments. The rest of your comment is irrelevant. Your “problem” is that something which you didn’t specify in the input arguments doesn’t show up in the input arguments. Of course, the actual purpose of the Java Agent is not, to show up in the input arguments, so you shouldn’t use that as indicator for the question whether the agent works.

Comment: @Holger Okay I think I got what you meant now. This was a silly question. I need to ask another question to solve my problem. Thanks